# Putting a multiple choice checkbox in a workflow in Sharepoint Designer 2013

Tags: workflow, multiple-values

I have a column in my SP which asks if 3 things are done and a checkbox for each. Once all 3 are checked as being done, I'd like an email sent to certain people in my Workflow. I don't understand how to get the checkbox options to be in the workflow. I'm sorry I'm not sure how else to word this, but I'll be happy to try to clarify if I'm not being clear.

I need this:

[image: column]

to relate to my workflow here but I only see Yes/No options in the value If/Then statements: 
[image]

Comment: I found information on Initiantio Form Parameters and it looks like only drop-down arrows or radio buttons can be used and only 1 value can be checked at a time. Maybe having multi-select checkboxes just aren't possible in a Workflow? Form field type #7 https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-workflow-initiation-form-26879578-a62b-4fef-8b7e-9e4400afc94b#bm2

Answer (score 0):

You could do this. Fire this workflow off on creation.

```
Set field Date = today
Wait until Setup Workstation changed
Loop until Condition = yes

Set workflow variable (WorkToDo(String)) to = Workstation (make sure return field is Choices, Comma Delimited)
If WorkToDo = Desk Location Confirmed,Computer Imaged,Email Accounts Created
____
Send email
Set Field condition = yes
____
Else 
Add 2 hours to $date
pause til $date
___
End loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've done that in the past.
First, I add a hidden text field to my list called LastSetupWorkstation

Then, in workflow that runs on an item changing, check to see if all the boxes are checked - you have to use 'contains'.
If they're all checked, see if the last field is missing any of those - that means the current change has a new checkbox.
Once you're done, set the hidden field to the value of the actual field, so you don't do an email when another field changes.

```
    If CurrentItem:SetupWorkstation not equals CurrentItem:LastSetupWorkstation
        If CurrentItem:SetupWorkstation contains Desk Location
        and CurrentItem:SetupWorkstation contains Computer
        and CurrentItem:SetupWorkstation contains Email Accounts

             If CurrentItem:LastSetupWorkStation does not contain Desk Location
             or CurrentItem:LastSetupWorkstation does not contain Computer
             or CurrentItem:LastSetupWorkstation does not contain Email Accounts
                 email whomever....
   then Set LastSetupWorkstation to CurrentItem:SetupWorkstation
```